# Install IJulia notebook on non-networked windows machine?

Tags: julia, jupyter, jupyter-notebook, ijulia-notebook

As a long-time user of Matlab for scientific computing, I am exploring Julia as an alternative but would like to use it within the Jupyter notebook.

I have Julia-0.4.5 installed and functional,  and previously downloaded the IJulia notebook installation zip file from [github](https://github.com/JuliaLang/IJulia.jl/blob/master/README.md).
However, the installation instruction `Pkg.add("IJulia")` seems to require network access. My machine is currently not networked.

*Anaconda3*: installed and functional

*IPython Notebook*: installed and functional (currently Jupyter only runs the python3 kernel)

**Edit**:

The Julia documentation gives the following instructions. However,  I do not have a another machine to determine the directory from.

> **Offline Installation of Packages**
>
> For machines with no Internet connection, packages may be installed by copying the package root directory (given by `Pkg.dir()`) from a machine with the same operating system and environment.
>
> `Pkg.add()` does the following within the package root directory:
>
> - Adds the name of the package to `REQUIRE`.
> - Downloads the package to
>   `.cache`, then copies the package to the package root directory.
> - Recursively performs step 2 against all the packages listed in the package’s REQUIRE file.
> - Runs `Pkg.build()`

Comment: Check the manual for offline installation of packages: http://docs.julialang.org/en/release-0.4/manual/packages/#offline-installation-of-packages

Comment: @amrods Thanks. I have gone through the julia documentation but still do not have an existing IJulia directory to copy from. Also, it is not clear where to paste the copied files? (See the except in the edit above)